# LG Smart tv Volume Controlling

Tags: javascript, audio, volume, television, lg

I'm making app for LG smart tv and need to controll volume. The main purpose of APP is make iPad or phone able to remote controlling. 
Media Player Plugin hasn't methods which controlls volume. 
Sound plugin has only method `sound.play()`.

I have successfully completed this task for Samsung smart tv using `plugin.setVolumeWithKey(volume)`.

If you have any ideas, please, help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Connect SDK. We offer this capability on Android, iOS, and PhoneGap/Cordova for the 2012, 2013, and 2014 model year LG Smart TVs.

http://www.connectsdk.com/
http://connectsdk.com/apis/1-2-1/ios/volumecontrol/